# Configuring SAML for Apache Guacamole using the docker image

Tags: docker, saml, guacamole

I'm trying to setup Guacamole Docker with SAML authentication and I'm not sure how to provide the need parameters as env variables to the container. These are the attributes the SAML extension requires/accepts:

**saml-idp-metadata-url**

**saml-idp-url**

**saml-entity-id**

**saml-callback-url**

**saml-strict**

**saml-debug**

**saml-compress-request**

**saml-compress-response**

**saml-group-attribute**

I want to know how to set up my docker run command to direct the container to use SAML, utilizing the provided environmental variables

for example:

docker run --name some-guacamole \
--link some-guacd:guacd \
--link some-mysql:mysql \
-e MYSQL_DATABASE=guacamole_db \
-e MYSQL_USER=guacamole_user \
-e MYSQL_PASSWORD=some_password \
-e MYSQL_PASSWORD=some_password \
-e SAML_IDP_METADATA_URL=http:\\someurl\meta.xml\ 
-d -p 8080:8080 guacamole/guacamole

If this is not the right way of going about this I would appreciate any alternatives

Guacamole docs on SAML configuration:
https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/saml-auth.html

Guacamole Docker image:
https://hub.docker.com/r/guacamole/guacamole

Answer (score 1):

The method I used was to link a local directory to the docker container (guacamole/guacamole) via `-V /etc/guacamole:/etc/guacamole`.

In the mentioned directory add a nested directory called `extensions` and place the .jar extension from guacamole in the location.

Add another file called `guacamole.properties` in this file use the configs mentioned like such:

```
saml-idp-url:  #https-url-no-quotes
```

Do this for the following pieces then restart the docker container and should automatically redirect.